# Action required: Make sure your ads are set appropriately for the intended audience of your app

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console

How to solve this problem.

Thanks for reaching out to the Google Play team.

Thanks for submitting Nargin musiqi pleyer (com.music.musiqi) to Google Play. After review, your app has been rejected due to a policy violation. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

Issue: Violation of Inappropriate Ads policy

The ads shown within your app must be appropriate for the intended audience of your app, even if the content by itself is otherwise compliant with our policies. For example, ads that show mature content or services cannot be served in apps that have a content rating for younger audiences.

Action required: Make sure your ads are set appropriately for the intended audience of your app

Read through the Inappropriate Ads policy, Content Ratings page, and Help Center article for additional details.
Take appropriate steps to ensure that your ads services and ad content filtering are set appropriately for the content rating of your app.
You may need to check with your ad service provider to make sure the advertising campaigns you selected will only show content consistent with your app’s intended audience.
If you use AdMob, please refer to the AdMob Help Center for more details on ad content filtering.
Sign in to your Play Console and submit the update to your app.
If you’ve reviewed the policy and feel our decision may have been in error, please reach out to our policy support team. One of my colleagues will get back to you within 2 business days.

Thanks for your continued support of Google Play.

Best,

The Google Play Review Team

Comment: This is off-topic in Stack Overflow since this it's not related directly with programming. Flagged as Off-topic

Comment: So what solution did you use? Setting `"max_ad_content_rating","G"`? I'm not sure how good it is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134528/rating-for-ads-google-console-and-12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how correctly to write this in C# Unity3d?

public static AdRequest createAdRequest ()
{

```
        return new AdRequest.Builder()
            .AddExtra("max_ad_content_rating","G")
            .Build();
}
```

This case do not working. I can see ads 16+
Is there need to choose additive options in AdMob site?

Comment: My ads stopped working after setting this filter - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134528/rating-for-ads-google-console-and-12

Answer (score 9):

If you are using admob only, it is possible to just update the settings in admob website:

1. Select your app
2. Click on "Blocking Controls"
3. Click on "Ad Content Rating"
4. Set to "G" General Audience.

With these settings it is not required to set "max_ad_content_rating" in the code. So no need to submit a new build, unless you are already using "max_ad_content_rating". In that case, you might need to remove it to avoid overriding.

Comment: I already did this after getting rejection! but how can i bring back my app online since it snowing it is removed from play store.

Answer (score 7):

According to Google documents, just change your **AdRequest** code to the following:

```
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("max_ad_content_rating", "G");

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
        .build();
```

In the last code, I set the String **"G"** because content rating for my app is "+3", and you have to change that according to Google documents.

Look this table:

[image: digital content label corresponds to your app audience]

Comment: I did this and still got the notification is there any other issue?

Comment: @RafaelLima Did you succeed after this change in your code?

Comment: My ad banner stopped working after setting this filter - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134528/rating-for-ads-google-console-and-12

Comment: If you are using admob only, is it possible to just update the settings in admob website (Blocking Controls -> Ad Content Rating -> Set to "G" for your app) ? Is it really required to set "max_ad_content_rating" in the code ?

Answer (score 4):

[image][image]I just resolved this case for my app in Google Play

1. No changes in programming code are necessary!
2. In Google Play Console, for your application, fill correctly Content Ratings and Target Audience.
3. In Google AdMob click on your app and choose Blocking Controls/Ad Content Rating. Then set Ad Content Rating to corresponding value of Content Ratings and Target Audience in Google Play Console. In my case it was G.

Answer (score 2):

Google:  "Make sure the advertising campaigns you selected will only show content consistent with your app’s intended audience."

Set the maximum ad content rating that's suitable for your app users (Content Rating)

[image]

Note that this will impact the revenues as it will not show ad content including topics  mature audiences, alcohol, weapons and sexual content.

Comment: should we change the app content rating of the play store so that it will not affect the revenue?

Answer (score 0):

For the Flutter Application you can use the below method

```dart
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

final RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration =
        RequestConfiguration(maxAdContentRating: MaxAdContentRating.g);

MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(requestConfiguration);
```